# cap deploy no output, no errors but does not deploy

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have what was a working capistrano deployment this morning. It still deploys to other instances, but any new instances I try to deploy to, I get no output. I don't get errors either. It doesn't return anything and the instance is not deployed. I'm pretty new to capistrano, so I might be overlooking something obvious. I have a trace of an unsuccessful deploy here:

https://gist.github.com/jslusher/3a29375f6324ec0ee125

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Here is an example of a successful deploy to a separate instance: https://gist.github.com/jslusher/686bc19e06dc7304d96a

Comment: An update. This has something to do with the cap-ec2 plugin this is using. For some reason, even though the instance has the ec2 tags capistrano is looking for, capistrano doesn't see the instance and therefore it doesn't think it has any instances to deploy to. As to why it doesn't see the tagged instance, I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

This was hard to track down, and it's an error specific to the way we're deploying these instances. The problem was with the knife ec2 server create command. The command got changed to the following:

```
knife ec2 server create ..... -T "roles=rails_server, apps=rails, environment=staging "
```

Notice the whitespace after the word staging. That was being added to the tag and therefore it was not being picked up by cap-ec2.